# Construct an order-preserving bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a countably dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been stuck on this problem (not homework, just an additional exercise) for quite some time now and I wanted to see if you folks had any ideas:

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a countable dense subset. Construct an order-preserving bijection $f:\mathbb{Q}\to K$.

Comment: Since this essentially shows that the order type of the rationals is unique, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=order+type+rationals+unique) should be helpful. Also, the standard method of proof uses something called the "back and forth method".

Comment: Please don't remove your question. If you found it answered in another post, you can edit to link that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two enumerations $K=(a_k)_{k\ge 1}$ and $\Bbb{Q}=(b_j)_{j\ge 1}$.

For $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ set $f(n)$ to the first element of the sequence such that $a_k\in [n,n+1)$.

- Then repeat:

  take the first $b_i$ not set yet, take the rationals $u<b_i<v$ such that $f(u),f(v)$ are already set and nothing in $(u,v)$ has been set.  ​Set $f(b_i)$ to the first $a_k$ such that $a_k\in (f(u),f(v))$.

This will give an order preserving injection $\Bbb{Q}\to K$ and it is not hard to see that every element of $K$ will be the image of some rational.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $A$ be a  totally ordered set with a labelling $N \to A$ ( $N$ is $\mathbb{N}$ or a segment of it).   Construct the [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) associated to $A$ with its labelling.

Fact: if $A$ has no largest nor smallest element and  is dense in itself ( for every $a<b$ in $A$ there exists $c$ in $A$ with $a< c< b$), then its binary search  tree is the complete infinite rooted binary tree (not hard to show, also the converse).

Get the bijection ( embedding) using the binary search trees.